# How can I adjust the font size of chapters in table of content?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have preparing my thesis with the following packages. The table of content appears in the output is shown in the uploaded figure. The chapter titles are abnormally large and I want to reduce it. Please help.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{Thesis}
\graphicspath{figures/}  
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{vector}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, citecolor=red}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfigure,caption,multirow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,29,119}
\newcommand{\itemcolor}[1]{% Update list item colour
\renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{\color{#1}\hfil ##1}}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{float}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{graphics,psfrag}
\usepackage{graphicx,psfrag}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter    

\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}

\tableofcontents
```

[image: content output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This is probably due to the  `Thesis` class. Check  how it defines the layout of  the table of contents. Unrelated: you don't have to load `epsfig` nor `graphics` if you load ` graphicx`, and `hyperref` should be the last pckage loeded, with the exception of `cleveref`.

Comment: Are you using `\chapter{\large Title...}` or something similar?

Comment: @Bernard, Thanks for your package-suggestions. I cant figure it out where can I make adjustments in thesis.cls file. Shall I copy the file content in this string?

Comment: @Werner, Yes I am using \chapter{\Huge Title...}.

Comment: Could you just post a link to the  .cls file?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid setting font-related settings with every call to `\chapter`, or any sectional unit for that matter; it's better to stick to the regular semantic use and define such formatting options globally. This allows for better consistency and ease of updating/change in the future.

Try any one of the following options (since `Thesis` might not allow some...):

- If `Thesis` is based on [`book`](//www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co) or [`report`](//www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls?view=co), patch `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead` with [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

  ```
  % ...
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \makeatletter
  \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}% <cmd>
    {\huge}% <search>
    {\Huge}% <replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
  \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}% <cmd>
    {\huge}% <search>
    {\Huge}% <replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
  \makeatletter
  % ...
  \chapter{...}
  ```
- Use [`sectsty`](//ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) (or [similar](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/1455/5764)):

  ```
  % ...
  \usepackage{sectsty}
  \chapterfont{\Huge}
  % ...
  \chapter{...}
  ```
- Manually update `\chapter` to include `\Huge`:

  ```
  % ...
  \usepackage{xparse}
  \let\oldchapter\chapter% Store \chapter in \oldchapter
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{s o m}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
      {\oldchapter*{\Huge #3}}% \chapter*{...}
      {\IfValueTF{#2}
         {\oldchapter[#2]{\Huge #3}}% \chapter[..]{...}
         {\oldchapter[#3]{\Huge #3}}% \chapter{...}
      }%
  }
  % ...
  \chapter{...}
  ```
- Update `\huge` (the default chapter font size) to `\Huge` temporarily:

  ```
  % ...
  \usepackage{xparse}
  \let\oldchapter\chapter% Store \chapter in \oldchapter
  \let\oldhuge\huge% Store \huge in \oldhuge
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{s o m}{%
    \let\huge\Huge% Update \huge to be \Huge
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
      {\oldchapter*{#3}}% \chapter*{...}
      {\IfValueTF{#2}
         {\oldchapter[#2]{#3}}% \chapter[..]{...}
         {\oldchapter{#3}}% \chapter{...}
      }%
    \let\huge\oldhuge% Restore \huge font
  }%
  % ...
  \chapter{...}
  ```
- Manually supply a non-`\Huge` optional argument:

  ```
  \chapter[<main title>]{\Huge <main title>}
  ```

Comment: Thanks @Werner. I have just removed all font related settings and the problem solved.

Comment: @som: Good. Consider [accepting this as the answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764).